# How to write "to toss and turn" in German?

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

> Jedes Mal, wenn seine Mutter sich bewegt, schreit das Baby laut.

How do you say "to toss and turn" in German? In my dictionary it's "sich krümmern", yet I am not sure if it is the right verb in this context.

Comment: Is it really "sich krümmern" and not "sich krümmen"? Sounds like a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to "hin und her wälzen" is "herumwälzen":

> Immer wenn seine Mutter sich (im Bett) herumwälzt, schreit das Baby laut.

And even worse would be "herumwerfen":

> Mein Kind hat Albträume und schläft kaum noch. Es wirft sich nur die ganze Nacht im Bett herum.

Answer (score 5):

sich (im Bett) hin und her wälzen (=to toss and turn [in bed])

> Immer wenn seine Mutter sich hin und her wälzt, schreit das Baby laut.